# Meaning of $\stackrel{*}{\rightarrow}$ production rule?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, notation

I've seen the production rule $\stackrel{*}{\rightarrow}$ in some papers concerning regular languages.

What's the meaning of $\stackrel{*}{\rightarrow}$ production rule?

Comment: This is in the context of grammars, right?

Comment: I've placed the * where it belongs. Look at the source to see how.

Comment: @RickDecker I've certainly seen it in the other place, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's either the transitive closure or reflexive-transitive closure of $\rightarrow$. That is, $A\rightarrow B$ means that you get from $A$ to $B$ in exactly one step; $A\rightarrow^*B$ means either you get to $B$ in one or more steps (transitive closure) or in zero or more steps (reflexive-transitive closure).

Comment: * is reflexive, + is only transitive.

Comment: @calmyoursenses I would encourage everyone to use the notation that way but I can't guarantee that everybody actually does.